# do calculation when angular select drop down event is finished

Tags: javascript, angular, events, select, customization

I am using angular(7) and my client needs to do heavy calculation when given certain select drop down value is selected without having button click. I did it and now I got some lag when user selects drop down value(because calculation happens with change event trigger). So I need to fix that thing.
As a initial work around, I thought it would be ideal to have a try by beginning the calculation after drop down event is finished or make that (change) event method asynchronous. I have tried (keyup) event with select event, it did not work and it seems angular is not recommended to use that way. Please give me any suggestion for this.

```
<select class='form-control' [(ngModel)]='selectedBaseYearParam1' (change)='selectParam1BaseYear(segments)'>
    <option *ngFor='let obj of pastYears' [value] ="obj.value">{{obj.year}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to optimize the wrong thing. The `change` event should be the way to go here. You should be probably be asking how to optimize your calculation instead since it shouldn't take that long ideally. If your calculation happens through a backend call (which should be the case if it takes that long, no calculation that heavy should be done in the client-side), then I'd suggest you use a loading icon or something of the sorts.

Comment: Hi nash11,
Thanks for your comment, I have already put loader and stuff but the thing is calculation takes it time, not an issue, but I just need complete select event non blocking with calculation.

Comment: Try writing the one more method (selectChanged()) and trigger that with (change). Now call the  selectParam1BaseYear(segments) method inside selectChanged(). So that whenever you trigger change the selectChanged gets  called and select event will be completed. now your calculation part will be done after selecting.